# How can I get the value of a textbox using jquery class selector?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

how can I get the value of a textbox using jquery class selector?

My html looks like this:

```
 <input class="TextBoxTime" id="time2" name="time2" type="text" value="01:30 AM" />
```

I want to get the value without using the id because I’m creating the id during run time.  I’m trying to do something like this:

```
 var theClassTime = $("input.TextBoxDate");

 $("#saveBtn").click(function () {

         $("input[name='selectedCourses']").each(function (i) {
             if (this.checked) {
                var theTimes = theClassTime.find('input:eq('+ i +')').prop('selected', true).val();
                alert(theTimes);
             }

         });



     });
```

How can I get to the value of this input element without using it’s id?

Answer (score 0):

Live demo : **http://jsbin.com/mibid**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input class="my" type="text" value="a" />
  <input class="my" type="text" value="b" />
  <input class="my" type="text" value="c" />
  <input class="my" type="text" value="d" />
  <input class="my" type="text" value="e" />

  <button onclick="show()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>


<script>
  function show(){
    $(".my").each(function() {
     var val = $(this).val();
     alert(val);
  });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following are multiple ways to access give item.

```
.class  $(".intro") //All elements with class="intro"
.class,.class   $(".intro,.demo")// All elements with the class "intro" or "demo"
element $("p") //   All <p> elements


:first  $("p:first")    The first <p> element
:last   $("p:last") The last <p> element
:even   $("tr:even")    All even <tr> elements
:odd    $("tr:odd") All odd <tr> elements
```

To get All input elements with type="text"   `:text $(":text")`

to get the values just use val() from that control.